# Adding array of strings and array of doubles in a combobox

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to add an array of strings to an array of doubles.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim items() As String = {"Beef", "Chicken", "Lamb"}
    Dim itemcosts() As Double = {7, 4, 3}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_starttest.Click
        cmb_test.Items.AddRange(items + items)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It returns an error that I cannot add two strings.

Comment: You need to change `AddRange(items + items)` to `AddRange(items)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `+` operator doesn't do at all what you want for array. The only good news here is you're working with a combobox, so what it really wants is all strings. That means you can do this:

```
cmb_test.Items.AddRange(items.Concat(itemcosts.Select(i=>i.ToString())).ToArray())
```

Comment: hey thanks for your response. when i run the program now it gives me the error that 'i' is not declared? do i have to declare it as a varible?